# How are referenced asset gains routed in a credit derivative?

Tags: derivatives, accounting, structured-credit

Lets assume for the sake of the example that we are talking about a Total Return Swap. The flow diagram is something like this.

[image]

Lets assume the *Payer* in this instance is a Hedge Fund, and the *Receiver* another Hedge Fund.

Since the assets are never sold, but rather remain in possession of the *Payer* how does the "accountability" process take place. In other words, how does the total receiver know that the *reference asset gains* that he is receiving are in fact accurate, or, that in the case of a credit event, he can verify that the spread he gets requested to pay-out is also accurate.

It would be massively helpful to have a breakdown of the various stakeholders and interactions when executing in practice a TRS.

Apologies if the question is quite broad, i am new to all of this.

Answer (score 2):

A TRS is very rarely between Hedge fund 1 and Hedge fund 2 (how would they find each other?).  Much more likely that it is between Hedge Fund 1 and a Dealer.  In the latter case, one of the counterparties must act as Calculation Agent, and it is almost always the Dealer.  The Calculation Agent has the responsibility of marking to market the asset, for the purposes of determining the cashflows that you have described.  Often , the Hedge Fund has "dispute rights" that enable it to challenge the actions of the Calculation Agent.  These Dispute Rights might specify that the Hedge Fund can appeal to a panel of 5 banks to determine the asset value, for example.  The result of this poll would be legally binding.

Comment: `Hedge Fund_1` and `Hedge Fund_2` is just for illustration purposes, as requested by the `OP`. As an `OTC` instrument, nothing prevents a financial institution to find and match the interests of 2 of its Hedge Fund clients although it might not be a general practice.

Answer (score 2):

In general any OTC trade (in your case total return swap) between two parties (i.e. buyer - Party A and dealer - Party B) shall and would be driven off a legal document which sets out transaction details. In most of the cases such legal document would be ISDA Master agreement and it's annexes (if any). There should be a notion/definition of a "Calculation Agent" who would compute and determine amounts. Usually Calculation Agent would be Party B (dealer). As for the actual amounts itself - it would depend on the underlying asset, i.e. if it's a listed security then Party A (buyer) could easily verify amounts and question Party B if unable to reconcile.

Have a look at a template [Master Bond Total Return Swap Derivatives Confirmation Agreement](http://www.isda.org/cgi-bin/_isdadocsdownload/download.asp?DownloadID=307) and you'll grasp an idea on who and how computes the amounts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Interesting question**, and let's briefly start with a conventional definition of *Total Return Swap* (assuming the **reference asset** is a **stock index**). As a matter of fact a *TRS* is an agreement to exchange the total return (*dividends + capital gains*) realized on a stock index for either a *fixed* or a *floating rate of interest* (e.g *LIBOR, LIBBOR + spread (in basis points)*) as very-well summarized in your picture. 
Both exchange of cash flows between the *Fixed-leg Payer* and the *Floating-leg Payer* being applied on the swap notional amount.

*For concreteness purposes, it's worth adding an additional stakeholder (*Broker*), thus the parties in a TRS generally involve:

1- **Hedge Fund_1** (as requested)

2- **Hedge Fund_2** (idem)

3- **Prime Broker** , holding the reference asset (e.g *proprietary index*, etc.) and also generally acting as a **Counterparty** of the trade.

**In an attempt to avoid any *Informational Asymmetry*, *Moral Hazard*, etc., the *Broker* (e.g *Custodian Bank*) is performing the computations (compute *Index levels*, *Returns*, at `time t`, mostly for proprietary indexes) and disclose it (on its website or on request) for *transparency purposes* while valuing the swap (*Mark-To-Market*) in accordance with the terms of the contract/agreement stipulated in the *Swap Term Sheet*. For instance it could be stated in the *Term Sheet* that `Hedge Fund_1` pays *15 basis points* or *LIBOR + 10 bp* to `Hedge Fund_2` if:

The `Index level is > a defined threshlod` (yesetrday's value),

Otherwise receive from `Hedge Fund_2` the return at `t` on the index.

The latter document could be obtained on request from the `Counterparty` of the trade, if neither `Hedge Fund_1` nor `Hedge Fund_2` has their own copy internally. It's worth stating that these agreements have *legal* implications, thus are generally signed by all the parties.

Ps: *Mark-to-Mark value* of the swap is also disclosed in the *Net Asset Value (NAV)* file sent frequently by the *Fund Administrator* to the Hedge Fund Managers (`Hedge Fund_1` or `Hedge Fund_2`).

**In the case of *Credit Derivatives*, the *Reference Asset* is usually `iTraxx`, but the above logic applies as well.

Hope it helps